# How can I represent a key value structure in Apache Solr efficiently

Tags: solr, indexing, range, wildcard

I have a structure of names and dates, that are stored in a log table. They represent user actions and when they did that.

```
Name        Date
John A.     2013-04-01
Leev B.     2013-04-02
Anse E.     2013-04-03
```

I need to index that data, keeping the relation between name and date.
I've already tried to concatenate the fiedls, using a separator ($):

```
"John A.$2013-04-01"
"Leev B.$2013-04-02"
"Anse E.$2013-04-03"
```

It worked fine, but from now on, users can search by a portion of the name, without typing it completely, and use a range for the date. So a ordinary search would be:

```
fq = log_user_date:["John*2013-12-01" TO "John*2013-12-31"]
```

It happens that Apache Solr cannot handle a query range with a wildcard in the middle of it.

There is a better solution for indexing "key value" data?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you concatenating the name and the date with a delimiter? You can instead keep two separate fields: a string field `name` and a date field `date` in Solr and do a query like

```
q=*:*&fq=name:John*&fq=date:[2013-12-01T00:00:00Z TO 2013-12-31T11:59:59Z]
```